# deserialize char Array to int and int[] and struct?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, embedded, deserialization

Can I populate a `struct` by treating it as an array of `unsigned char` values?

I receive character data over the RS232 UART from a Microcontroller. Using C, how can I deserialize the char Array in my Datatypes uint16_t, uin32_t, int32_t[], ...

e.g.

```
uin16_t StartID = ARRAY[0];
uin16_t EndID = ARRAY[246];
```

... is there something like this ? 
In C# there are effective functions for deserialization but im not that in C

for later

```
if (StartID == 11)
    printf("good"); 
else 
    printf("bad");
```

I made this struct to work easier later with the Data. Is there a way to get the Data from my ARRAY[248] into my struct?

```
typedef struct
{
  //Header 6byte
  uint16_t StartID; // Check if its 1 or in hex 0b
  uint16_t ID;      
  uint16_t LoadID;  

  //Payload 240 byte
  int32_t POS01[3];  
  int32_t POS02[3];
  int32_t POS03[3];
  int32_t POS04[3];
  int32_t POS05[3];
  int32_t POS06[3];
  int32_t POS07[3];
  int32_t POS08[3];
  int32_t POS09[3];
  int32_t POS10[3];
  int32_t POS11[3];
  int32_t POS12[3];
  int32_t POS13[3];
  int32_t POS14[3];
  int32_t POS15[3];
  int32_t POS16[3];
  int32_t POS17[3];
  int32_t POS18[3];
  int32_t POS19[3];
  int32_t POS20[3];

  //End 2byte
  uint16_t EndID; // Check if its 47 or in hex 2F

} DATA_POS; //TOTAL = 248byte
```

Comment: If the struct is laid identical to the ARRAY the following 2 options may work. DATA_POS data_pos; memcpy((void*)(&data_pos), ARRAY, sizeof(DATA_POS)); or DATA_POS *data_pos = (DATA_POS*)ARRAY;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C has a feature called `pointers`:

```
uin16_t *StartID = (void*)&ARRAY[0];
uin16_t *EndID = (void*)&ARRAY[246];
```

Other means to access data under another format include `unions`:

```
   union 
   {
      uint32_t *u32;
      uint16_t *u16;
      uint8_t  *u8;
   } u;
```

As you can see, sometimes features do not need a dedicated function.

Beware however that alignment issues could arise on some platforms because of accessing data in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of similar approaches. You could use a C `union`, which avoids the use of explicit pointers. You could use 'memcpy' to copy the contents of the `unsigned char[]` into the memory of a `DATA_POS` structure. Or you could write directly over that memory while reading from the serial port.

You didn't mention whether endianness is a concern, so I'll address that too.

A `union` lets you access the same block of memory as different data types. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define chars_per_int (sizeof(int) / sizeof(char))

// Note that every member of a union exists at the same memory location,
// so changing the value of one will change the value of all
union IntAsChars {
    unsigned int integerValue;
    unsigned char characterValue[chars_per_int];
};

int main() {
    int i;
    union IntAsChars value;

    value.integerValue = 0x1234abcd;

    for (i = 0; i < chars_per_int; i++) {
        printf("Character value is: %x\n", value.characterValue[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above code treats the same `sizeof(int)` bytes as a string of character values, and prints the numeric value of each.

Based on your code, you're looking for a union like

```
union data_representation {
    unsigned char char_data[248];
    DATA_POS data_pos;
};

union data_representation data;
```

This would let you fill `data.char_data` from the serial part, but refer to `data.data_pos.StartID` from your code.

Note, however, that different architectures can store the individual bytes of an integer in different order. Intel architectures traditionally use small-endian representations. The output of the code above will be different on x86:

```
Character value is: cd
Character value is: ab
Character value is: 34
Character value is: 12
```

and SPARC:

```
Character value is: 12
Character value is: 34
Character value is: ab
Character value is: cd
```

The safest general approach is to send big-endian data between systems (in this case, via the serial port) and use `ntohs` / `ntohl` to convert to the local host's representation. These functions convert "network" (big-endian) short (`ntohs`) or long (`ntohl`) data to whatever format is used by the local system. `ntoh` means `n`etwork `to` `h`ost, and the suffix is for `s`hort or `l`ong values. There are corresponding `htons` and `htonl` functions for converting from the host format into big-endian.

So you'd still populate `data.char_data`, but read the data using `ntohs(data.data_pos.StartID)` and `ntohl(data.data_pos.POS04[1])` to get the native values.

It might even make sense to make your own conversion routines so you don't have `ntohl`/`ntohs sprinkled throughout your code later. For example, the`convert_to_host_format` function below converts a 248-character input array to a DATA_POS structure with the appropriate endianness.

```
void convert_POS_to_host_format (int32_t dest[3], int32_t src[3]) {
    dest[0] = ntohl(src[0]);
    dest[1] = ntohl(src[1]);
    dest[2] = ntohl(src[2]);
}

DATA_POS convert_to_host_format (char buffer[248]) {
    DATA_POS host_data;
    union data_representation data;

    memcpy((void*)data.char_data, (void*)buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    host_data.StartID = ntohs(data.data_pos.StartID);
    host_data.ID = ntohs(data.data_pos.ID);
    host_data.LoadID = ntohs(data.data_pos.LoadID);

    convert_POS_to_host_format (host_data.POS01, data.data_pos.POS01);
    convert_POS_to_host_format (host_data.POS02, data.data_pos.POS02);
    convert_POS_to_host_format (host_data.POS03, data.data_pos.POS03);

    /* ... */

    convert_POS_to_host_format (host_data.POS19, data.data_pos.POS19);
    convert_POS_to_host_format (host_data.POS20, data.data_pos.POS20);

    host_data.EndID = ntohs(data.data_pos.EndID);

    return host_data;
}
```

If you wanted to skip the `union`, `memcpy` could be used to achieve the same results by writing directly over the memory holding the contents of `DATA_POS`:

```
void convert_POS_to_host_format (int32_t POS[3]) {
    POS[0] = ntohl(POS[0]);
    POS[1] = ntohl(POS[1]);
    POS[2] = ntohl(POS[2]);
}

DATA_POS convert_to_host_format (char buffer[sizeof(DATA_POS)]) {
    DATA_POS host_data;

    /* Write the contents of 'buffer' directly into the memory location of
     * 'host_data'.
    memcpy((void*)host_data, (void*)buffer, sizeof(DATA_POS));

    /* Convert values to host byte order in place. */
    host_data.StartID = ntohs(host_data.StartID);
    host_data.ID = ntohs(host_data.ID);
    host_data.LoadID = ntohs(host_data.LoadID);

    convert_POS_to_host_format (host_data.POS01);
    convert_POS_to_host_format (host_data.POS02);
    convert_POS_to_host_format (host_data.POS03);

    /* ... */

    convert_POS_to_host_format (host_data.POS19);
    convert_POS_to_host_format (host_data.POS20);

    host_data.EndID = ntohs(data.data_pos.EndID);

    return host_data;
}
```

You could even use a pointer while *reading* the UART data to write directly into the DATA_POS structure. The below treats the address of the structure (`&data`) as an unsigned character pointer.

It would still be a good idea to use a function like the convert_to_host_format structure above to address endianness concerns. If you don't need to be able to run on multiple architectures, though, the following should be enough to meet your needs.

```
DATA_POS data;
int i;
char *write_buffer;

write_buffer = (unsigned char*) &data;

for (i = 0; i < sizeof(DATA_POS); i++) {
    write_buffer[i] = read_byte_from_uart();
}
```

Please let me know if there's anything you'd like me to clarify.